# Is the differential of an integral an even or odd function?

Tags: integration, differential

If I have an integral of the type $\int \,d^3x$, is $\int \,d^3(-x)=-\int \,d^3x$? Does it even make sense to ask something about this? I was wondering about this but I can't understand if it is a well-posed question.

Comment: Assuming $d$ is acting on a vector $x$, then yes.